# Seemingly simple logic question

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

I found this pleasant textbook on Proof Theory online and free:

[Introduction to Proofs, an Inquiry-Based approach](http://joshua.smcvt.edu/proofs/)

To quote (page 9):

2.26 **DEFINITION**. A sequence $\langle x_0,x_1, . . . ,x_{n-1}\rangle$ is an ordered list of its terms $x_0, x_1, . . . , x_{n-1}$. Its length $lh(\langle x_0,x_1, . . . ,x_{n-1}\rangle)$ is the number of terms $n$. Two sequences are equal if and only if they
have the same length and the same terms, in the same order.

2.27 **EXERCISE**. Prove or disprove:

(i) $\langle3, 4,5\rangle = \langle4, 3,5\rangle$

(ii) $\langle3, 4, 4,5\rangle = \langle3, 4,5\rangle$

I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Do you understand what "Two sequences are equal if and only if they have the same length and the same terms, in the same order" means? You don't, for if you did, you'd know how to solve the problem. So I ask you what don't you understand in this sentence?

Comment: Check the definition requirements: if they are all satisfied, the sequences are equal (due to 'if'); if any is violated, sequences are different (due to 'only if').

Comment: so use *reductio ad absurdum*?

Comment: By the way, this isn't Proof Theory. Proof Theory is something else.

Comment: @GitGud; what I don't understand is that the Q is therefore not very difficult really is it?, so why is it in an adult textbook?

Comment: No, use the definition. Hint by analogy: Suppose you have a definition 'A natural number is 'even' if it can be divided by $2$ without a remainder'. How would you prove that $8$ is an *even number*? How would you disprove $\pi$ is an even number?

Comment: The question is actually very simple, but allows several omissions, so it may serve as a training case for proving or as a test of the prover's skills.

Comment: if someone could therefore just write an answer, like I asked....

Comment: TeX notation note: the angle brackets are symbols different from less-than and greater-than — they are invoked in (La)TeX with commands \langle and \rangle: $\langle\ and\ \rangle$.

Comment: @CiaPan; thanx, have fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose

(i) $\langle 3, 4,5\rangle = \langle 4, 3,5\rangle$

is true. Let's try to prove it then.

According to the definiton, two sequences must

1. be the same length,
2. have the same items, and
3. have their items in the same order

to be equal.
So we check:

1. The number of terms in LHS: 3; in RHS: 3 — they are equal; CHECKED.
2. The items of LHS sequence are 3, 4, and 5; RHS sequence: 3, 4, 5 — same; CHECKED.
3. In the LHS sequence 3 precedes 4, in RHS it goes after 4 — the orders differ; FAILED.

Sequences do not meet all definition criteria, so they are **not equal** (because of 'only if' – any requirement missed causes the 'not equal' answer).

Our initial supposition is disproven.

Comment: this is ok, but I re-checked the definitions, and <4,3,5> is an **ordered sequence** of its terms, and so **IS** equal to <3,4,5>

Comment: @JonMarkPerry You're right about being an ordered sequence, but you're wrong about the implication. To find out where you make a mistake, please explain in details your understanding of **ordered sequence**.

Comment: ok, got it, its roughly speaking a coordinate system, so you are right. just for fun, does <3,4,5>=<3,4,5> (with proof obviously)?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Sure it does! The two sequences have equal lenghts, same terms and same order of the terms, so they are equal. BTW it's not necessarily a coordinate system. You can have e.g. a sequence whose first term is a body, the second is a point in a space and the third one is a vector; such sequence may represent a dynamic state of a moving body (say, an asteroid)....

Comment: @JonMarkPerry ...A [polygonal chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_chain) can be represented as a sequence of points (vertices), each of which is itself a sequence of numbers (coordinates). A [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28mathematics%29) is formally represented as a three-term sequence, whose terms are a set, a 'plus' operator and a 'dot' operator (that is two binary functions working more or less like addition and multiplication within a given set).